# Which is faster: to filter a table beforehand, or use a Where statement?

Tags: sql

I'm currently inserting a lot of data into a new table, and wondering which way would be faster?
Would either of these ways be faster, or are they actually equivalent?

Option 1:

```
insert into NewTable
select * from (select * from OldTable where CONDITION)
```

Option 2:

```
insert into NewTable
select * from OldTable
where CONDITION
```

Thank you

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Have you simply tried benchmarking both queries?

Comment: Can you just try?

Comment: it's a lot of data (hours to run) just wanted to ask to see if anyone knew beforehand!

Comment: what would be the point to use option 1 anyway? Makes no sense to me. That's pretty much the same weirdness as `select * from (select * from (select * from table))`. it works, but makes no sense at all.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)

Comment: thank you! I was thinking having it there would filter the table before inserting, whereas option 2 would first insert all rows. But now I can see they're doing the same thing! Thx

Comment: I am just wondering what thought process you would have where the *same* query in a subquery would be *faster*.  In practice, they would have the same performance.  But I can't think of how the subquery could be faster.

Comment: Now that you say it I see it. I'm new to sql :)

Answer (score 1):

In most modern databases those two queries would be evaluated and rewritten by the optimizer such that they would be executed absolutely identically

There might be some old/dumb db out there that prepares the results of the inner then prepares the results of the outer, meaning the `select * from (select * from` would take slightly longer, but I wouldn't expect you could find such behavior easily.

SQL Server 2008 is the oldest DB I have:

[image]

(though I'm sure I have Access 97 round somewhere)

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking that but wanted to ask in case